# how copy the first elements of pair in vector to another vector?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a std::vector with element of the type std::pair. With some algorithm, I return two iterators (range) so I would like to pick up all elements within that range and copy the first entry of the pair to another vector

```
std::vector< pair<double, int> > data;
std::vector<double> data2;
std::vector< pair<double, int> >::iterator it1, it2;

for (;it1!=it2; it1++)
{
  data2.push_back(it1->first);
}
```

Using a loop will do that but I wonder if there is a straightforward stl algorithm to do that. Since the data size if pretty big and above operation will be repeated for many times, using a loop is pretty slow.

Comment: Whether you write the loop by hand or use a Standard Library algorithm, you still have to iterate over every element of `data`. You can make it prettier but it will take just as long. (Suggestion: use `data2.reserve()` to save some memory (re)allocation time).

Comment: If this operation happens very often and is more important than the data locality of the pair then you could try to use `std::pair<vector<double>,vector<int> > data;` instead. Then always access it with `data.first[i]` instead of `data[i].first`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are after an algorithm to do this for you, you can use the four parameter overload of [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
#include <algorithm> // for transform
#include <iterator>  // for back_inserted and distance

....
std::vector< pair<double, int> > data;
std::vector<double> data2;
data2.reserve(std::distance(it1, it2));
std::transform(it1, 
               it2, 
               std::back_inserter(data2), 
               [](const std::pair<double, int>& p){return p.first;});
```

If you don't have C++11 support, you can use a function instead of the lambda expression:

```
double foo(const std::pair<double, int>& p) { return p.first; }

std::transform(it1, 
               it2, 
               std::back_inserter(data2),
               foo);
```

Comment: thanks. but it doesn't compile, it reported error in the expression [](...), does it mean my compiler doesn't support this syntax? Also, does it have to reserve the size for data2 first? I am copying the data from iterator it1 and it2 (not all) to data2, so how do I estimate the size within that range?

Comment: @user1285419 looks like your compiler doesn't support C++11 then, you can replace the lambda with a pointer to a function that does the same (or a functor).

Comment: @user1285419 Maybe your compiler does not support C++11. In this case, you can declare a function that does the same thing as the `[]` line, and pass that function to `std::transform`. You don't have to call `reserve`, it is to avoid some re-allocations. I will edit my answer to use the two iterators.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The select operator `.` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`.

So what the compiler thinks you're writing is

```
*(it1.first)
```

when you mean

```
(*it1).first
```

Comment: It would have been so much easier to write `it1->first` :)

Comment: Thanks I modified the code already. But I am still looking for a fast stl algorithm instead of loop to achieve it.